# Android database query

Tags: android

I have a database table with 3 columns: _id, name, groupName

It looks similar to this:

1    Tom    group1

2    Sam    group1

3    Ted    group2

4    Jerry  group3

5    Me     group3

I want to query the database table for groupName. I have tried this:

```
public Cursor getAllGroups() 
{
      return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE_1, new String[] {KEY_GROUP}, 
            null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

And this returns a cursor along: (group1, group1, group2, group3, group3).

Is there a way to get only unique groups? (So I would end up with a cursor along: (group1, group2, group3)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need use raw SQL query with DISTINCT keyword. Rough code would be something like:

```
db.rawQuery("select distinct groupName from "+DATABASE_TABLE_1, null);
```

Here is SQL tutorial about the keyword http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-distinct-sql-tutorial/

Comment: I read through the tutorial and it looks like the code you posted should work (but it doesn't...). 

Does anyone know of a tutorial which explains how to create SQL queries - i.e. how to use the rawQuery function? I actually need a cursor over the KEY_ID AND the KEY_GROUP_NAME columns. How do you make a rawQuery that returns a cursor over multiple columns? 

I know how to do this with the regular query function:

    db.query(DATABASE_TABLE_1, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_GROUP},   null, null, null, null, null);

But how to do this with rawQuery?

Comment: I haven't played with it yet but the MOTODEVSTUDIO has a tool to build queries I think

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
db.rawQuery("select distinct column1, column2, column3 from tablename", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Wow. I figured it out. I am just posting this to help others who may have the same problem as me.

Steps for successful query building (for Android dev):

1) Download and launch "RazorSQL"

2) Connect to your database (follow on-screen instructions)

3) Click "DB Tools" -> "Query Builder" -> "Your database table name"

4) Graphically build your query (play around with everything, then click "Generate SQL")

5) Copy the SQL statement, and paste it in the RazorSQL editor window

6) Click the green arrow ("->"). Your query is now performed on your database and the results are displayed!

7) Copy the SQL statement, go to "Eclipse" (Android dev environment) and paste it as a string into a rawQuery() function

Cool!

So, the correct answer to my question is this:

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, groupName FROM titles GROUP BY groupName", null);
```

--> I discovered the "GROUP BY" by playing around in the graphical SQL builder

Have fun with SQL Queries!