# how to get unique values from sql database

Tags: java, android, sql

The following code gives all values from database even duplicate values.

```
return database.query("contacts", new String[] {"_id", "name"}, 
     null, null, null, null, "name");
```

how can i get distinct values from above code

Comment: You should probably use `rawQuery` instead of `query` and use a real SQL query with the `DISTINCT` keyword to perform this action. See also a [similar question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489280/android-database-query).

Comment: @JohnWillemse: Why not use the overload of `query` as indicated by Stefan's or my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [overload of `query`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) that takes a boolean as first parameter and remove the `_id` column from the select:

```
return database.query(true, "contacts", new String[] {"name"}, 
                      null, null, null, null, "name", null);
```

The `_id` column is supposed to be unique, so including it in your query will lead to the distinct having no effect.

Comment: of course it does. Becouse you select the primarey key "_id" also. That _id is always unique...

Answer (score 1):

Use distinct keyword this will return unique record from database.

```
db.rawQuery("Select DISTINCT from table_name",null);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this query:

```
public Cursor query (boolean distinct, String table, 
                 String[] columns, String selection, 
                 String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, 
                 String having, String orderBy, String limit)
```

set the first param to true and do not use youre primarey key in selection. it will be always unique...